# Must “signs” and “indications” be followed by a gerund?

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Must “signs” and “indications” be followed by a gerund?

Which of the following is correct?

1. There are signs **shows** that a mother is always a woman.
2. There are signs **showing** that a mother is always a woman.
3. There are indications **shows** that a father is always a man.
4. There are indications **showing** that a father is always a man.

Comment: No, they don't have to be. Ex: I drove by the signs. Ex: Can't you see the signs?

Comment: Those are not gerunds. They're attributive verbs (a verb describing an associated noun)  saying what the signs or indications are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not compulsory for them to be *always* followed by a ***present participle*** (and not a [gerund](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund), which can be used as a noun), but they can certainly not be followed by a verb, as you suggest in *1 and *3). These are cases of ***reduced relative clauses***:

> We can use *participle clauses after a noun* in the same way *as relative clauses*. This gives more information about the noun. We sometimes call this *a 'reduced relative clause'*.
> *A **present participle (verb + ing)** can be used in the same way as **an active relative clause***:
>
> - The man ***driving*** the car is a friend of mine.
>   (= The man ***who is driving*** the car is a friend of mine). ([perfectenglish grammar](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-clauses.html))

So you can either say:

> There are signs/indications ***showing***

or

> There are signs/indications ***that/which show***

Bear in mind that ***show*** must be in the plural, as it modifies "that/which" referring to the *plural* noun *sins/indications*.